# Orthogonal projection of $u$ onto plane spanned by two vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $$u=\begin{pmatrix}
> 4 &2  &1\end{pmatrix},v_1=\begin{pmatrix}
> \frac{1}{3} &\frac{2}{3}  &\frac{-2}{3} 
> \end{pmatrix},v_2=\begin{pmatrix}
> \frac{2}{3} &\frac{1}{3}  &\frac{2}{3} 
> \end{pmatrix}$$
>   be vectors in the standard Euclidian space $\mathbb{R}^3$.
>
> a) Find the component of $u$ orthogonal to the plane spanned by the vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$, and confirm that this component is orthogonal to the plane.
>
> b)Find the orthogonal projection of $u$ onto the plane spanned by the vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$.
>
> Solution. Cross product
>   $$v_3=v_1\times v_2=\begin{vmatrix}
> i &j  &k \\ 
> \frac{1}{3} &\frac{2}{3}  &\frac{-2}{3} \\ 
> \frac{2}{3} &\frac{1}{3}  &\frac{2}{3} 
> \end{vmatrix}=\frac{2}{3}i-\frac{2}{3}j-\frac{1}{3}k$$
>   Now, the component orthogonal to the plane is the projection of $u$
>   onto $v_3$ parallel to the plane
>   $$pr^\perp_{v_3} u=(u.v_3)v_3=1.v_3=\begin{pmatrix}
> \frac{2}{3}
>  &\frac{-2}{3}  &\frac{-1}{3} 
> \end{pmatrix}$$
>   To solve b) consider
>   $$u-pr^\perp _{v_3} u=\begin{pmatrix}
> \frac{10}{3} &\frac{8}{3}  &\frac{4}{3} 
> \end{pmatrix}$$
>   My question is does the last equation belong to the plane (because it is perpendicular to $v_3$) and therefore is the desired projection - or have I gone off the path?

Comment: This is correct.